# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I know this question has been asked several times. But I haven't seen an explanation of the error.
My directory

```
(bug-tracker) ➜  bug-tracker git:(initial-setup) ✗ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   └── __init__.py
└── webapp
    ├── __init__.py
    └── app.py
```

`export FLASK_APP=app:webapp` I have this in the environment.

`__init__.py` is empty
Contents of `app.py` are

```
from flask import Flask
# from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlachemy

app = Flask(__name__)
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgresql://localhost:5432/bug_tracker'

# SQLAlachemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  """ Print hallo world as the response body """
  return 'hello, world'
```

Very basic but giving me headache. Please explain a bit your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
export FLASK_APP=app:webapp
```

It has to be

```
export FLASK_APP=webapp/app.py
```

The explanation - the Flask command line tool needs to know where your Flask app is.

Comment: Glad I could help!